# Using VBA to loop a set of commands, =XMLFILTER does not update the URL when a new URL is pasted

Tags: excel, vba, xml-parsing

I am using Bing maps API to try to generate distances, then I am pasting these distances in excel.

The process seems to be:

1- Generate a URL.

2- Parse the xpath: CallbackUrl parameter found in the first URL.

3- Parse the xpath: ResultUrl parameter found in the second URL.

4- Parse the xpath: TravelDistance to grab the distance.

Problem is step #3, ResultURL does not update automatically. It shows as #Value! until I select the cell and press Enter.

- I tried setting up VBA to select the cell and press enter.
- I tried setting up VBA to write the cell contents:

`Sheets(ref).Range("C17").Value = "=FILTERXML(WEBSERVICE(C16)," & Chr(34) & "//ResultUrl" & Chr(34) & ")"`

- VBA does not want to update that cell value.

The cell C16 should be:

```
=FILTERXML(WEBSERVICE(C16),"//ResultUrl")
```

And it should update to a new URL whenever C16 updates. Instead, whenever C16 updates with a CallbackUrl, C17 goes to #VALUE! error.

Comment: As you are using a CallbackURL, I presume that you are making an asynchronous call to the [Distance Matrix API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/routes/calculate-a-distance-matrix). It seems possible that the request hasn't fully completed when you first check the CallbackURL and thus there is no ResultURL in the returned data. You could test for this by using `=FILTERXML(WEBSERVICE(C16),"//RequestId")` as this value should always be present

Comment: It's the [Truck Routing API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/routes/calculate-a-truck-route). Yes, the Distance Matrix API has no CallbackUrl, but the Truck Routing does. Everything works in excel when I do it manually cell by cell. Only thing that does not work is that the ResultUrl does not pickup the CallbackUrl when the CallbackUrl changes.

Answer (score 1):

I added a wait 5 seconds in between calls and it works. It turns out it took a few seconds to generate the URL.